# Submit and edit value in the same form in AngularJS

Tags: json, forms, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have just started using AngularJS. 
I would like to send **and** edit value in the same form.
Here is my approach :

- I fill the input with the scope `array` with ng-init.
- And with the scope `fields`, I store the new value when I click on the button **submit**.

But it doesn't seem to work... I don't understand why.

**index.html**

```
 <form class="form" name="myForm" novalidate>

    <div class="col span12 input"><input type="text" ng-model="fields.name" ng-init="array.name" required /></div>

    <div class="col span12 input"><input type="text" ng-model="fields.age" ng-init="array.age" required /></div>

    <select ng-model="fields.po_id" ng-init="fields.po_id" ng-options="productOwner in productOwners" required></select>
```

ng
        Add

```
 </form>
```

**controllers.js**

```
$scope.productOwners =
[
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 4
    },
];

$scope.array =
[
    {
        "name": "Hello"
    },
    {
        "age": "18"
    },
    {
        "po_id": "2"
    }
]; 

$scope.submit = function(fields){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wGHe1NZNaGoW1I6Xr5Sx?p=preview) solving your issue.

You had two issues in your code:

1) `ng-init="array.age"` should be `ng-init="fields.age=array.age"` and same thing for the other `ng-init`.
You wasn't saving the value in `fields` so it wasn't updated.

2) Your array definition was faulty.

You should either define array as:

```
$scope.array = {
        "name": "Hello",
        "age": "18"
    };
```

Or change the call to array in the HTML template like that:

`array.name` -> `array[0].name`

`array.age` -> `array[1].age`

---

**EDIT:**

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wGHe1NZNaGoW1I6Xr5Sx?p=preview)

The correct use of [ng-options](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) is

```
for array data sources:
   label for value in array
   select as label for value in array
   label group by group for value in array
   select as label group by group for value in array
for object data sources:
   label for (key , value) in object
   select as label for (key , value) in object
   label group by group for (key, value) in object
   select as label group by group for (key, value) in object
```

So I've changed your ng-options from `ng-options="productOwner in productOwners"` to `ng-options="productOwner.id for productOwner in productOwners"` which is of the type : `label for value in array` where the `label` is `productOwner.id` and the value is the object `productOwner`.

Moreover, the `ng-init` is not needed since `fields.po_id` has no value at the initialization.

But if you want to initialize the value, you can do something like :

```
ng-init ="fields.po_id = productOwners[0]"
```

Comment: Oh ! Thanks, it seems to work. Can you check my last edit with the select ? The select doesn't pre-selected the option. It's always empty...

Comment: Yeah, but precisely `fields.po_id` should have a default value at the initialization. It must have the value from `"po_id": "2"`.  The value pre-selected is `2` but I would like to show the others options with `ng-options="productOwner in productOwners"`

Comment: I just tried it initialize = `<select ng-model="field.po_id" ng-init="field.po_id = 1"></select>` It doesn't work :(

Comment: `1` is not contains inside the array productOwners. If you want to initialize the value, you must either pass an object for example `ng-init ="fields.po_id = productOwners[0]"` or change the `ng-options` to `ng-options="productOwner.id as productOwner.id for productOwner in productOwners"` but then you won't be able to retrieve the others informations linked in the product owner

Comment: It would be better to move the expressions in the ng-init to the controller. See the description of [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) on the angular site which recommends 'The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat'